# Заменить страницу 404 на страницу с каталогом

Tags: error404

Я хочу настроить redirect с несуществующей страницы на страницу со всей продукцией. Сейчас redirect на страницу 404. Может ли это иметь какие-то негативные последствия? Зачем нужна страница 404?

Comment: Если используете flask, то через декоратор errorhandler: app.errorhandler(404) и дальше в функции редирект, тогда каждый раз, когда будет 404 на вашем сервере, то будет вызываться ваша функция с этим декоратором. Ошибка 404 означает, что заданного адреса не существует